# Adding extra texts to nodes in tikz automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, automata

I want to draw a diagram like the one shown below.

[image]

However, the nearest I can come up with is the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname TD.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=20.0mm, auto, on grid, thick] 
    \node[state,initial] (0)   {0}; 
    \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {1}; 
    \node[state,accepting] (2) [right=of 1] {2}; 
    \node[state,accepting] (3) [below=of 2] {3}; 
    \node[state,accepting] (4) [below=of 3] {4}; 
    \path[->] 
    (0) edge node {$<$} (1)
    (1) edge node {$=$} (2)
    (1) edge [bend right] node {$>$} (3)
    (1) edge [bend right] node {other} (4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\input {\jobname TD.tex}

\end{document}
```

As, you can see, I do not know how to add those **return** texts
in nodes 2, 3, 4
or that * in node 4.

Comment: You did the hard work, now just add nodes right to other nodes.

Comment: @CroCo Want to show how do I do this? I am rather a copy-paste guy when comes to tikz. And positioning of those texts is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the `label` key for the already existing nodes; you can use it as many times as required to place several labels at different positions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname TD.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=20.0mm, auto, on grid, thick] 
    \node[state,initial] (0)   {0}; 
    \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {1}; 
    \node[state,accepting,label={right:\textbf{rerun ( relop, \texttt{LE})}}] (2) [right=of 1] {2}; 
    \node[state,accepting,label={right:\textbf{rerun ( relop, \texttt{NE})}}] (3) [below=of 2] {3}; 
    \node[state,accepting,label={right:\textbf{rerun ( relop, \texttt{RE})}},label={60:$\ast$}] (4) [below=of 3] {4};
\path[->]    (0) edge node {$<$} (1)
    (1) edge node {$=$} (2)
    (1) edge [bend right] node {$>$} (3)
    (1) edge [bend right] node[swap] {other} (4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\input {\jobname TD.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname TD.tex}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=20.0mm, auto, on grid, thick] 
    \node[state,initial] (0)   {0}; 
    \node[state] (1) [right=of 0] {1}; 
    \node[state,accepting] (2) [right=of 1] {2}; 
    \node (return1) [right=of 2,xshift=3mm] {\textbf{return ( relop, LE)}};
    \node[state,accepting] (3) [below=of 2] {3}; 
    \node (return2) [right=of 3,xshift=3mm] {\textbf{return ( relop, NE)}};
    \node[state,accepting] (4) [below=of 3] {4}; 
    \node (return3) [right=of 4,xshift=3mm] {\textbf{return ( relop, LT)}};
    \node (inv) [below=of 3,xshift=3mm,yshift=7mm] {\textbf{*}};
    \path[->] 
    (0) edge node {$<$} (1)
    (1) edge node {$=$} (2)
    (1) edge [bend right] node {$>$} (3)
    (1) edge [bend right] node {other} (4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\input {\jobname TD.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Are those absolute shifts important? Is it possible to use relative shifts?

Comment: No, you can increase/decrease the space as you wish.

Comment: Why additional nodes? It's simpler to use `label` for the already existing nodes..

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, you are right. I just added them in case the OP needs to move them around.